# When is it Lobster Season in the Caribbean?

Tags: seasonal, caribbean, bahamas, turks-and-caicos

Just finished reading an entire guidebook on the Caribbean and whenever it mentions that a restaurant serves lobster, they put in parenthesis `when in season` yet nowhere does it say when that is.

**When is lobster season exactly?** Does it vary by island? Are there yearly patterns?

Although not technically part of the Caribbean islands, I would like to include  Turks and Caicos plus The Bahamas, since those are the islands I am likely to see next .

Comment: Took me 10 seconds to google it: https://www.uncommoncaribbean.com/caribbean/when-is-lobster-season-in-the-caribbean/

Comment: Very nice find! They even include TCI. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The season does differ by island, although a closed period from April/May to July/August is more common than any other.

Some places have no closed season, some have a closed season which is in a different time of the year and some have a much longer closed season.

You can find [the details on this site](https://www.uncommoncaribbean.com/caribbean/when-is-lobster-season-in-the-caribbean/), (from the comment by @Sebastian.)

> Destination   Open    Closed
>   Anguilla    All year
>   Antigua     July 1 – April 30   May 1st – June 30th
>   Aruba   July 1 – March 31   April 1 – June 30*
>   Bahamas     August 1 – March 31     April 1 – July 31
>   Barbados    September 1 – April 30  May 1 – August 31
>   Belize  June 15 – February 14th     February 15 – June 14
>   British Virgin Islands  November 1 – July 30    July 31 – October 31
>   Cayman Islands  December 1 – February 29    March 1 – November 31
>   Cuba    June 15 – February 14th     February 15 – June 14*
>   Dominica    All year
>   Dominican Republic  August 1 – March 31     April 1 – July 31
>   Grenada     September 1 – April 30  May 1 – August 31
>   Jamaica     July 1 – March 31   April 1 – June 30
>   St. Kitts & Nevis   All year
>   St. Lucia   August 2 – February 28  March 1 – August 1
>   St. Martin/St. Maarten  All year
>   St. Vincent & The Grenadines    September 1 – April 30  May 1 – August 31
>   Trinidad    All year
>   Turks and Caicos    August 2 – March 31     April 1 – August 1
>   U.S. Virgin Islands     All year
>   *I’m a little uncertain of these dates

(The table did not copy well, but the information is clear on the site.)

Comment: The saying _only in months with "R" in the name_ seems to be somewhat accurate!

Comment: I take it you are not familiar with the months Mach and Apil or Jrune and Jurly ;-)